# 401 Unauthorized Response from Apple New Publisher API

Tags: java, http, spring-boot, http-status-code-401, apple-news

I want to access my channel with the apple new publisher API. I am trying to replicate the same python in the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/News_API_Ref/SecuritySampleCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015409-CH8-SW1)

```
String finalUrl = baseURL + channelId;  
String date= getCurrentDate();  
String canonical_request = "GET"+finalUrl + date;  
String authHeader = "HHMAC;key="+apiKeyId+";signature="+getSignature(secret, canonical_request)+";date="+date;  
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().build();  
HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.get()  
.setUri(finalUrl)  
.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader)  
.build();  
CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

How I get the signature:

```
private static String getSignature(String secret, String data) {  
     Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");  
     SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");  
     sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);  
     return Base64.encodeBase64String(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(data.getBytes()));  
}
```

I am always getting 401. The python code is working. I tried to replicate the error from the python code and it happens only when I don't set the authorization header and not when the signature is wrong (also according to apple news publisher API [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/News_API_Ref/SecurityErrors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015409-CH7-SW1)) which means somehow the header is not set. You can check the whole request [here](https://requestb.in/ua98l8ua?inspect)

Comment: Check whether getSignature(secret, canonical_request) return and the Python signature are equal.

Comment: @shazin they cannot be equal but I can see that the header is being set at least. If the signature is wrong I should have received another error.

Comment: @shazin I am not sure if the header is being set correctly..